# C# Graphics Book

Tags: c#, excel, graphics

I'm interested in using C# for graphics work.  The book I have doesn't seem very interested in graphics.  Could someone suggest a book that is more graphics-oriented?  I am also interested in C interfacing with Excel.  I'd be very grateful for any advice.
Thanks!

Comment: What kind of graphics are you talking about?

Comment: Just in general.  I've looked through the book I have, and it doesn't even discuss how to initiate a graphics screen or draw a line.  I don't need the fanciest graphics in the world.  Probably pretty basic stuff would be fine.

Comment: Do you have prior graphics experience or are you also looking for a primer on that?  Are you using WPF?

Comment: I used to do some graphics with Borland C years ago.  I've forgotten quite a bit of that, unfortunately.  I'm not familiar with WPF.  I just want to get started on some graphics work and I need the fundamental stuff.

Comment: C# does not have graphics. WinForms, WPF and even ASP.NET do.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend getting started with [XNA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/aa937791.aspx). Some books are as follows:

- [Rob Miles - Free Drafts](http://www.robmiles.com/xna-book-downloads/)
- [Professional XNA Programming: Building Games for Xbox 360 and Windows with XNA Game Studio 2.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470261285)

Comment: Thanks, Rob.  I'll look into XNA.